# Named format placeholders in ReSharper annotations?

Tags: c#, annotations, resharper, string.format

ReSharper has the fantastic `StringFormatMethodAttribute` annotation which provides code analysis for format strings and their parameters. It can be added to any custom string format methods like this:

```
[StringFormatMethod("format")]
void DebugFormat(string format, params object[] args);
```

This works well when using integer placeholders, e.g.:

```
x.DebugFormat("ReSharper is {0} for {1} placeholders", "great", "numbered");
```

However, some libraries (like [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) and [ASP.Net Core / Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/#log-message-template)) offer *named* format placeholders which are used for (semantic | structured) logging and this seems to be something that ReSharper does not (yet) offer. For example, a line of code like this:

```
x.DebugFormat("ReSharper is {Quality} for {Style} placeholders", "poor?", "named");
```

Results in the ReSharper code analysis warning

> Format item index must be a number starting 0 without leading or trailing whitespaces

Searching on ReSharper support, this site, and Google draws a blank. Has anyone found a way to get string format annotations working with named placeholders?

Relevant JetBrains links:

- [ReSharper help on StringFormatMethodAttribute](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#StringFormatMethodAttribute)
- [ReSharper help on custom string formatting methods](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__String_Formatting_Methods.html#custom)

Comment: My read is that they're somehow using `string.Format()` in the implementation, which is why only integers are supported.

Comment: Seems that Serilog added a custom attribute: `MessageTemplateFormatMethod` is used by their [`ILogger`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/ILogger.cs) and used by the [SerilogAnalyzer](https://github.com/Suchiman/SerilogAnalyzer).

Comment: [Serilog's MessageTemplateFormatMethodAttribute](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/Core/MessageTemplateFormatMethodAttribute.cs) | [NLog's MessageTemplateFormatMethod](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/dev/src/NLog/Attributes/MessageTemplateFormatMethodAttribute.cs) | [ReSharper issue RSRP-480001](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-480001)

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented an R# extension for this. Download it [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12083-structured-logging) from JetBrains.

It is also [hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/olsh/resharper-structured-logging).

This extension highlights structured logging templates and contains some useful analyzers. Here is how the structured logging events look with the plugin installed:

[image]